# When was LUKS first released?

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption, luks, dmcrypt

When was [Linux Unified Key Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) (LUKS) first released--both as an open standard and later made available as an implementation with [cryptsetup](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup)?

Answer (score 0):

## Timeline

Here's the best timeline I could get from Google on the evolution of LUKS and `cryptsetup`:

### 2004

- `Mar 04`: [First commit](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/aecd010c3b2f38e42d837d1f5a0aef9b782c7223/ChangeLog) to the cryptsetup code repository
- `??? ??`: First proof-of-concept ([source](https://clemens.endorphin.org/p/about-me.html))

### 2005

- `Jan 22`: [LUKS1 On-Disk Format Specification](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf) released
- `Mar 25`: cryptsetup [version 1.0](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/aecd010c3b2f38e42d837d1f5a0aef9b782c7223/ChangeLog) released

### 2012

- `Apr 23`: [Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.10_(Quantal_Quetzal)) includes checkbox for [FDE in GUI installer](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/11/privacy-ubuntu-1210-full-disk-encryption)

### 2017

- `Dec 11`: LUKS2 became available with [cryptsetup v2.0.0](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/bca8a32674140d2e15ff1fdb18d1cc005e1ead19/docs/v2.0.0-ReleaseNotes)

### 2018

- `Aug 02`: [LUKS2 On-Disk Format Specification](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/LUKS2-docs/blob/master/luks2_doc_wip.pdf) released

### 2019

- `Feb 08`: LUKS2 became the default with [cryptsetup v2.1.0](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/6a740033def543bda71b0f5cf1b775121fd3631c/docs/v2.1.0-ReleaseNotes)

### 2020

- `Feb 08`: [Debian 10](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/) is released, using [LUKS2 by default](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/mips64el/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#cryptsetup-luks2)

## Resources

- [Clemens Fruhwirth's blog](https://clemens.endorphin.org/)
- [Cryptsetup gitlab.com repository tags](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/tags)
- [Old cryptsetup repository (googlecode)](https://cryptsetup.googlecode.com/)